# Different between earned points and total points

Tags: bug, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I've earned 50 points by asking questions on stackoverflow but my points total shows 51. How come? [This is my account profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1735053/pierre-rymiortz?tab=reputation). I don't have enough points to post a screen shot.

Total shows 51.

Reputation history shows 29 + 12 + 2+ 5 +2 = 50;

Comment: Although it's hidden toward the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start at 1...

Comment: Oh...I'm speechless. Sorry for posting such a silly question.

Comment: :-), don't worry